# Get NULL value percentage for multiple columns

Tags: sql, oracle

I'm trying to get the percent of NULL values for multiple columns as well as some other details on the number of rows (total, NULL, not-NULL). The below query works fine, but just for a single column:

```
SELECT
    COUNT(1) as total_all,
    COUNT(c_name) as total_not_null,
    COUNT(1) - COUNT(c_name) as total_null,
    (COUNT(1) - COUNT(c_name)) / COUNT(1) as percent_null
FROM t_name
```

There are about 120 columns I need to go through. Is there any way to do this for multiple columns as well as display the column name in results?

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.

Comment: What is `NULL` for multiple columns? All of them have `NULL` value or any `NULL`? You may cast everything to char, do concatenation and do count of this expression for any number of columns

Answer (score 1):

You could:

- `unpivot` all the columns you want to check (making sure you `include nulls`)
- Map to values for null/non-null using a `case` expression or similar
- Group the result of this by column and use `ratio_to_report` to get the percentage null/non-null for each column

Which looks like:

```
with vals as (
  select department_id, 
         commission_pct, 
         manager_id 
  from   hr.employees
), rws as (
  select col, case when val is null then 'Y' else 'N' end as is_null 
  from   vals
  unpivot include nulls (
    val for col in (
      department_id, commission_pct, manager_id 
    )
  )
)
  select col, is_null, count (*), 
         round ( 
           ratio_to_report ( count (*) ) 
             over ( partition by col ) * 100
         ) pct_split
  from   rws
  group  by col, is_null
  order  by col, is_null;
  
COL               IS_NULL  COUNT(*)   PCT_SPLIT   
COMMISSION_PCT    N              35          33 
COMMISSION_PCT    Y              72          67 
DEPARTMENT_ID     N             106          99 
DEPARTMENT_ID     Y               1           1 
MANAGER_ID        N             106          99 
MANAGER_ID        Y               1           1
```